# style css for columnar layout

Tags: html, css

In what follows, all files are in:

```
idf@:/var/www/mywebsite.com/html$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 idf  idf  4096 Mar 10 16:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar  1 11:06 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 idf  idf   922 Mar 10 15:30 icons8-gamma-48.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 idf  idf  1843 Mar 10 16:21 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 idf  idf   141 Mar 10 15:59 style.css
```

I have code like this:

```
style.css

.column {
  float: left;
}

/* Left and right column */
.column.side {
  width: 25%;
}

/* Middle column */
.column.middle {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Then in my `index.html` I want to divide a `frame` and a `widget` into left, middle columns using the `style.css` file, as described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_website_layout_grid). But this **doesn't** work. The page displays fine, but the layout is not columnar.

**What is correct html to layout into side-by-side columns using .css?**

```
index.html    

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Welcome to mywebsite.com!</title>
        <link rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          href="/icons8-gamma-48.png" />
    </head>
 <div class="column side">
   <iframe src="https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com?columns=exc_flags,exc_currency,exc_importance,exc_actual,exc_forecast,exc_previous&features=datepicker,timezone&countries=25,32,6,37,72,22,17,39,14,10,35,43,56,36,110,11,26,12,4,5&calType=week&timeZone=8&lang=1" width="650" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe><div class="poweredBy" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 11px;color: #333333;text-decoration: none;">Real Time Economic Calendar provided by <a href="https://www.investing.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px;color: #06529D; font-weight: bold;" class="underline_link">Investing.com</a>.</span></div>
</div>
<div class="column middle">
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
<div id="tradingview_c1ac3"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're experiencing is with you iframe content. It's set to `width="650"` which is more than the 25% (on most screen sizes) you have allowed for the side column. If you change the width of the iframe to 100% it will fit in the dimensions you need, but won't display the entire iframe content. You might have to play around with the width of the iframe to get your desired look.

You also need to put your columns in a row div which will allow you do your columns correctly.

**CSS**

```
**.column {
  float: left;
}
/* Left and right column */
.column.side {
  width: 25%;
}
/* Middle column */
.column.middle {
  width: 50%;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}**
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column side">
    This is text in left column.
  </div>
  <div class="column middle">
    This is text in middle column.
  </div>
  <div class="column side">
    This is text in right column.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made the width of the frame 100 which is  now all scrunched up (I also tried 100%). There is now plenty of room for the widget to display in the middle, yet it still displays beneath the frame.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Putting the columns in a row div which should work. Also good practise to clear the floats after the row.

Comment: I solved it by following exactly the template that I linked to (w3school) in the original post. I did have to play around with the width to make it look right.